# Continously Calling function while holding a react native touchable component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to simulate the progressive bar that is on Snapchat story when recording a story. Everything is done but the button touch effect. How do you call a function while holding the button, not just onPress?

Comment: you mean onLongPress? Or if you want to control the whole press duration, you can use onPressIn and onPressOut so that you know when the user is pressing it or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using one of the `Touchable` buttons, I would use a combination of the `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` props to perform an operation while the user is holding the button. See more info [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onpressin)